# RestSharp not returning any data?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

We are trying to test out a .Net 4.0 console app forcing it to use TLS1.2 and I'm not getting it to return any data.

If I use Postman and do a GET on `https://domainname.com/TestEndpoint/api/v1` then I get some simple text returned as it should.

If I use the following code in a .Net 4 console app and look at the `response.Content`, the data is blank. Am I doing something incorrect with RestSharp?

```
try
{
    //https://domainname.com/TestEndpoint/api/v1

    var endPoint = "https://domainname.com/";
    var client = new RestClient(endPoint);

    var request = new RestRequest("TestEndpoint/api/v1", Method.GET);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content; // raw content as string

    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Error("Error: {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: TLS 1.2 is not officially supported in .NET 4.0. However there is a workaround if you have .NET 4.5 installed on your machine and your project still targets 4.0. This [blog post](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/) gives some pretty helpful information

Comment: Yes, that's what we are trying to test. We have some 4.0 apps that are sitting on a server with 4.5 and we want to a simple console app that will first fail, then we make the registry change, and hopefully see it work. To test this all out I'm trying to write a simple console app in 4.0 along with a simple API that is forcing TLS 1.2.

Comment: Then all you have to do is add the line:
`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;` This is what tricks 4.0 into being compatible with TLS 1.2

Comment: First I would like it to fail, then I'll add that line and hope to see if succeed but I can't get the code to return anything on my local machine which does  support TLS 1.2

Comment: BTW, I'm not getting any errors when I run it locally. I'm just getting blank data when I expect to see something. It's like I have something in correct in the code but I don't see it.

Comment: The errors might fail silently.  Have you monitored the calls in Fiddler to see what the endpoint is actually returning?  Remember that you are in a bit of uncharted/weird territory by tricking 4.0 into being TLS 1.2 compatible...

Comment: I'm using Postman and not Fiddler but if I put in the API URL and do a get it returns simple text. In my case it's "Successful connection 5/10/2017 3:50:03 PM V1.0.0.0 010.045.048.216". That's what I'm saying it should be returning something and if there is any errors it should be caught in the Try...Catch. At least that's the way I thought it would work.

Comment: As far as I know Postman does not monitor your traffic right?  Fiddler does.  It succeeding in Postman does not help diagnose the problem with your code because Postman is TLS 1.2 compatible.  You need to see what your Console app requests are doing.  Either by monitoring its calls via Fiddler, or by diving deep into the objects that RestSharp returns to see if there are any messages that allude towards a failure.  RestSharp could be failing silently without throwing an exception

Comment: Finally got it. I had to look at the response object that was coming back. I was then able to see the Error Message. On my local machine (Win 7) it was only saying that it could not open a connection. I then put it on Server 2012 machine and I got much better message about not being able to make a SSL/TLS connection. I was then able to test both adding the ServicePointManager to see it work and then the Registry setting to make it work.

Comment: I'm going to add my portion of this conversation as an answer so future developers can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand you have .NET 4.5 installed on your machine, but your console app is targeting .NET 4.0.

The one line of code you need to make it work is:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Without that line, your requests to a TLS 1.2 endpoint will fail (as I know you are aware of already).

I suspect that your requests are silently failing, and not triggering the catch block. If you check your requests in Fiddler or in other traffic monitoring software you will likely see a response back from the server that says something to the effect of "SSL/TLS incompatibility".  RestSharp is likely suppressing any exception internally, or not throwing one at all (depending on the status code of the API call response).

**Tl;dr** Given our conversation in the chat, I know you know how to make it *work*.  Watching the traffic in Fiddler will tell you why its *failing*.

Comment: I have limited experience with Fiddler but I couldn't get it to show any traffic. If I went to a web site I could see traffic but nothing from running my console app locally. I'm betting I have a setting somewhere keeping me from seeing the traffic.

Comment: Since you are using https, you have to configure Fiddler to decrypt https traffic.

Comment: I know this is over a year old - but this is the only solution I could find online that actually worked. Kudos!